# Protractor (karma-jasmine) timeout issue

Tags: angular, google-chrome, protractor, karma-jasmine, selenium-chromedriver

Angular 4.4.5, Chrome 63, latest chromedriver: started receiving following error when running tests that i didn't encounter before (week ago): "Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within timeout specified by jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL."

Adjusting defaultTimeoutInterval, allScriptsTimeout, getPageTimeout didn't have any effect. Any ideas?

Comment: did you tried 
it('test case',function(){
}, Timeout here)

Comment: also if you share some code snip will help to debug.

Comment: won't matter what code i'll snip here, it's failing on expects() for css selectors, fails on browser.wait

Comment: _did you tried it('test case',function(){ }, Timeout here)_

yes

Comment: try by adding callback statement
it('test case', function(callback){
callback();//this needs to be added at the end of test case
});

Comment: callback statement didn't help

Comment: check if you have any undefined variable. This happens sometime if you use undefined variable.

Comment: You have either somewhere a bug in your code and start an unwanted async process or your tests need more execution time than available (jasmine default timeout). In both cases, please add some code samples, especially your mentioned `browser.wait` function.